# how to get coordinate lon lat from geoserver with openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver

I run this code to get all of my vector coordinates:

```
var ft = vectorSource[0].getFeatures();
    for(var i=0; i< ft.length; i++){
      document.getElementById('abc').innerHTML+=vectorSource[0].getFeatures()[i].getGeometry().transform('EPSG:3857','EPSG:4326').getCoordinates()
};
```

This is the result:

```
106.68594471683284,-6.145608605008391,106.68637254034257,-6.145584973628701
```

How can I get two numbers representing lon & lat from my vector?

i need result coordinate like following code from all my vector but without click the map

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
   var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
});
```

Comment: By the way, **"what are you doing"**? Which coordinates do you want? From feature? Are they `ol.geom.Point`?

Comment: pick either end or an average of the two depending on your use case